# Can $n$ Divide $!n$ for $n>2?$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, left-factorial

> For any positive integer $n$ the **left factorial function** is defined as
> $$!n = 0!+1!+2!+\cdots+(n-1)!$$

My work:

Consider a $p$-dimensional Euclidean space with orthogonal coordinates, and take the two vectors
$$ X = [ 0!, 1!, 2!,\cdots, (p-1)! ]$$ $$Y = [ (p-1)!,\cdots, 2!, 1!, 0! ]$$
The dot product (i.e., the scalar product) of $X$ and $Y$ is
$$X\cdot Y = (0!)(p-1)! + (1!)(p-2)! + \cdots + (p-1)!(0!)$$ $$=-1 (\operatorname{mod}p)$$
$$=|X|\cdot|Y|\operatorname{cos}\alpha$$
where $\alpha$ is the angle between $X$ and $Y$.  Since $X$ and $Y$ have the same components in reverse order, we know that $|X| = |Y|$, so we have
$$[ (0!)^2 + (1!)^2 + ... + ((p-1)!)^2 ] \operatorname{cos}\alpha =  -1  (\operatorname{mod} p)$$
This relates the sum of the squares of the factorials $0!$ to $(p-1)!$ with
the cosine of the angle between X and Y.  Of course, this doesn't prove that the sum of squares is not divisible by $p$, it just rephrases the question in terms of the cosine of the angle between two vectors.

For any positive integer $n$ let $![n,k]$ denote the sum of the $k$th powers of the factorials from $0!$ to $(n-1)!$  For example, the preceding formula can be written as $$![p,2]\operatorname{cos}\alpha = -1 (\operatorname{mod} p)$$
By Fermat's Little Theorem, the sequence of integers $![p,k] (\operatorname{mod} p)$ for $k=0,1,2,\cdots$ is periodic with a period dividing $p-1$.  Therefore, we have
$$![p,(p-1)m] = 0   (\operatorname{mod} p)$$ for any natural number $m$.

In general, we have $![p,k]=0 (\operatorname{mod} p)$ if and only $k$ is of the form  $(p-1)m + c$  where $c$ is one of a finite set of values for any given prime $p$  The question of whether $!p$ is ever divisible by $p$ is equivalent to asking if $c$ can ever be $1$.

I have calculated the values of $c$ for the first few primes but none of them came out to be $1$. After this I am stuck. Any ideas$?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems wird to put $\cos\alpha$ in a modular arithmetic question.

Comment: For formatting, use `\pmod p` rather than whatever you are using to write $(mod \,p)$

Comment: @DietrichBurde I know that.....can you escalate it more$?$

Comment: Yes, it is still an open conjecture.

Comment: @DietrichBurde you can put your thoughts on this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conjecture that $n$ does not divide $$
!n=0!+1!+2!+\cdots +(n-1)!
$$
for any $n>2$ was listed as B44 in R. Guy's "Unsolved Problems in Number
Theory" back in $1981$. As of today, no proof has been found, if I am not mistaken. For more details and a generalisation see [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24265/what-is-the-limit-of-gcd1-2-n-1-n).

Edit: In May of 2015, Vladica Andrejic and Milos Tatarevic found
that $![p,5]$ is divisible by $p$ for the prime $p = 9632267$.